# cut rows and column using last and tr

Tags: linux, bash, multiple-columns

The user selects the rows to cut from a ‘last’ command along with what columns
to cut. In addition to using variables, used ‘tr’ to
fix all the differences in white spaces. I tried following code but don't know where I went wrong.

```
echo -n "What rows and columns would you like to cut: "
read before
read after
read stop
read start
last | head -n $before friend_list | tail -n $after | tr -d $start $stop
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: A list of columns from a specific set of rows.

Comment: Can you give an example of the text you're starting with (from `last`), parameters a user might give, and the result they would expect?

Comment: Sara Lee Boston saralee@cake.com 2036539812
King Kong Tampa kingkong@universal.com 4076985643
Sea Lion Kissimmee sealion@open.com 3216984263
Bat Man Miami batman@help.com 7083336580
Bionic Women Dallas bionicwomen@savme.com 8132981165
Clark Kent Houston kent@globe.com 4316735208

Comment: The parameters would be a range of row numbers and a range of columns. The output would be the user defined rows with only the appropriate column information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *sounds* like what you want is this:

```
last | head -n $after | tail -n $((after-before+1)) | cut -f $start-$stop
```

which will output the subset of `last`'s output from line `$before` to line `$after`, from column `$start` to column `$stop`.

Comment: Thanks for the input but when I tried this I get the error "cut: invalid byte, character or field list

Comment: @user2133534: What are the values of `$start` and `$stop`?

Comment: There are a total 5 columns. The user has to choose the range

Comment: @user2133534: Sorry, but that's not what I asked. What I asked is, what are the values of `$start` and `$stop`? (What do you see when you add the command `echo "<$start-$stop>"` in your script?) The reason I asked this is, I posted a command that works properly if `$start` and `$stop` are as I expect (namely: if both are positive; `$stop` is greater than `$start`; and there is no extraneous whitespace).

Comment: When I echo "<$start-$stop>" I get an error message ./script_4: line 8: echo<5-4>: command not found. I am sorry I am a new user. I did it again putting the $stop > $start but it just prints the whole list and not the specific rows and columns requested

Comment: @user2133534: Setting aside the user-interaction for a moment . . . what do you see when you run `last | head -n 5 | tail -n 3 | cut -f 2-4`? That should show you columns 2-4 of lines 3-5.

Comment: I see the list which shows lines 2-4 but does nothing for the columns

Comment: I tried last | head -n 5 | tail -n 3 | cut -d " " -f 2-4 and it worked. Thank you so much for your help. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @user2133534: Ah, sorry, I should have tested with real output from `last`. `cut` expects the columns to be tab-separated -- or separated by a configurable character, but still, just one of it. `last`'s output doesn't seem to be very predictable in format; it doesn't even seem to be in real "columns", exactly.